# CSS3 background-position animation lags on mobile devices

Tags: android, css, background, background-position

I'm trying to create a scrolling effect for a background using CSS3 animations, such as:

```
body {
  background: url("bg.jpg") repeat-y 0 0;
  animation: animatedBackground 50s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes animatedBackground {
  from { background-position: 0 0; }
  to { background-position: 0 100%; }
}
```

([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ht11qxwj/1/))

This works great, except that it's very laggy on mobile devices (e.g. Android Chrome 43.0)). I've tried various hacks that are suppose to force the browser to use the GPU, which sadly didn't help.

One solution is to use `translateY` and duplicate the image, like [shown here](https://css-tricks.com/infinite-all-css-scrolling-slideshow/). That doesn't feel very good however, since the image is pretty big to start with. It does run smooth, though.

I'm looking for alternate solutions on how to make this run smooth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspired by the [link](https://css-tricks.com/infinite-all-css-scrolling-slideshow/) in the OP, I found a way to achieve this without having multiple references to the same image. It does, however, require you to know the image's height.

The general idea is to have a `relative` wrapper which hides all overflow, and force the image to be 200% its height, and make it `repeat` and finally animate the y-axis -100%. Example:

```
#parallax-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#parallax-background {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: @parallax-image-height * 2;
  background: url("/bundles/sunnerbergsimilarseries/images/tv-show-wall.jpg") repeat 0 0;
  animation: animatedBackground 50s linear infinite;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

@keyframes animatedBackground {
  0% { transform: translateY(0) }
  100% { transform: translateY(-@parallax-image-height) }
}
```

([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ht11qxwj/2/))

The above runs as smooth on a 2015 Android-phone as on a computer with a dedicated graphics card.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that `transform` runs smoothly while `background-position` does not is that `transform` can utilize the phone's hardware acceleration while `background-position` must rely on the browser software's re-rendering of the element.  Even if it's a large image, using hardware acceleration is *always* better for mobile.

If it's the same image, any browser worth it's salt isn't going to incur any extra impact by using it twice, as it's cached after the first pull.

So use the `transform` solution, and feel confident it's the right one.

Comment: You're absolutely right. Your answer motivated me to use the transform solution, however I found a way to avoid the duplicate image. Many thanks, much appreciated!